# RecyclerView gets confused when notifying changes manually and through the DiffUtil

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've got an interesting situation where my adapter has 2 view types - `HEADER` and `ITEM`. Header view is always at position 0. When I update my data, I use `DiffUtil` to get the diff of the data. To disptach the updates and rebind, I use a `ListUpdateCallback`:

```
private void dispatchUpdates(
        @NonNull final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter,
        @NonNull DiffUtil.DiffResult result) {
    result.dispatchUpdatesTo(new ListUpdateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
            adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(position + getItemOffset(), count);
        }
    ....
```

so I can add the offset (i.e. 1 cause of the header that's always present) to the position calculated by `DiffUtil` to update the correct elements. This works fine.

The problem happens when I also need to update the header. I manually calculate the header diff and notify the adapter. Together with `DiffUtil` the code looks like this:

```
        DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil
                .calculateDiff(new ItemDiffUtil(getItems(), newData));
        Bundle headerDiff = getDiffPayload(newData);
        dispatchUpdates(this, diffResult);
        if (!isNullOrEmpty(headerDiff.keySet())) {
            notifyItemChanged(0, headerDiff);
        }
```

This is refusing to play nicely. With multiple updates dispatched to the adapter (say, inserting 3 items), it gets confused and I can see duplicate items in my grid (just the thumbnails loaded through Picasso). If I comment out `notifyItemChanged(0, headerDiff);` the header is obviously not updated, but everything else works fine.

My question is whether it's possible to queue these updates in a more meaningful way so that I can still use the `DiffUtil` but my header gets updated as well?

EDIT: interestingly, the same issue persists if I use AirBnb's `Epoxy` instead of my own `RecyclerView` adapter

Comment: Could you also add your adapter code?

Comment: @atasoyh which part are you interested in? It's pretty big. Is it the binding you're after?

Comment: I just tought, sometimes we can make simple mistakes.. So I wanted to see your adapter for checking indexes, refs... But I got it, your problem is not about that..

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure why this is happening, but the culprit I think is `Picasso`. I've noticed a few things in the logs:

When the issue manifests, `Picasso` never completes the request:

```
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R14655] Request{content://com.app.myapp.contentprovider/thumb/20170705173259427 resize(534,534) centerCrop}
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R14655]+0ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R14655]+0ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      removed      [R14655]+4ms from 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  canceled     [R14655]+4ms
```

Also there's something weird happening with `Picasso` as it goes into an endless loop creating requests for each element in my grid:

```
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R14424] Request{content://com.app.myapp.contentprovider/thumb/20170705173054794 resize(534,534) centerCrop}
D/Picasso: Main        completed    [R14424] from MEMORY
<...> // repeated for each ViewHolder forever in an endless loop
```

Anyway, moving to [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) has solved the issue as far as I can tell.